# CoreBluetooth compatibility issues between CBCentralManagerState (iOS 5.x to 9.x) and CBManagerState (iOS 10.x or above)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, core-bluetooth, xcode8

From iOS SDK 10.0, the class `CBCentralManager` is now inherited from `CBManager`

`CBManager` is introduced in iOS 10.0, it is not available in earlier versions.

The `state` property is now enumerated as `CBManagerState`

`CBManagerState` is also introduced in iOS 10.0, it is not available in earlier versions.

Which means `CBCentralManager`’s `state` property is of type `CBManagerState`, which is only available on iOS 10.0

So when you read the state, you get a `CBManagerState`. But for earlier iOS versions, the type is not available, so you have to cast it to previously recognised (deprecated in iOS 10.0 though) `CBCentralManagerState` enumeration type.

```
CBCentralManagerState(rawValue: centralManager.state.rawValue) ?? .Unknown
```

Now you can use this `state` property into the earlier iOS versions. When your app will be prepared for iOS 10.0 or above, only then you can use it as `CBManagerState` directly.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39577272/how-to-convert-value-of-type-cbmanagerstate-to-expected-type-cbcentralmanager ?

Answer (score 0):

**'CBManagerState' is only available in iOS 10.0 or newer.**

Replace all your CBCentralManagerState and CBPeripheralManagerState enums by CBManagerState.
The enums are binary compatible so your code will run fine on any iOS version.
If you want to still be able to compile your code with Xcode 7, you can add some really simple defines.

```
#if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED <= __IPHONE_9_3  
#define CBManagerState CBCentralManagerState  
#define CBManagerStateUnknown CBCentralManagerStateUnknown  
#define CBManagerStateResetting CBCentralManagerStateResetting  
#define CBManagerStateUnsupported CBCentralManagerStateUnsupported  
#define CBManagerStateUnauthorized CBCentralManagerStateUnauthorized  
#define CBManagerStatePoweredOff CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOff  
#define CBManagerStatePoweredOn CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOn  
#endif
```

if you want to read more about this change please follow these link:

[Best practice for checking if an enum exists in iOS version?](https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/143024#143024)

[CBCentralManagerState deprecated iOS 10](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/51222)